# Javascript send string to console application

Tags: javascript, c++, http

I want to execute some javascript that will send a string of text to a c++/java console application running on the same machine as the web browser

What javascript should I execute? and how should I receive the string?

Comment: I recommend reading up on the security policies of browsers.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are two ways to transmit data to somewhere else using JavaScript. The first is using an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), the second is using a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets). In both cases, the JavaScript code will establish a connection to another program, which in this case you want to be your C++/Java program.

In the first case, if you want to communicate using an XMLHttpRequest (or other libraries that use this, such as jQuery's `get` or `post`), you'd need to make sure that your C++/Java application starts a small webserver. This way, the JavaScript code can establish a connection to it and send data. I'm sure there are C++/Java libraries which you can use for this, but even if you can't it should be fairly simple to get something to work with just plain socket code. The text-based HTTP protocol that you need for this is not that difficult.

In the second case, you'd need to make sure that a WebSocket server is started in your C++/Java application. Your JavaScript code then can connect to this server and just send its data. I'm not that familiar with the WebSocket protocol but I suspect that it's slightly less trivial, so using a library for this would be a good choice.

Comment: the WebSocket was the missing link in my problem :) I think I can make it work now, thank you